# Postgres SQL Query that returns JSON Object with IDs as dynamic keys

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to create a (postgres) SQL query that returns a (JSON) object with dynamic keys. Therefore I have created this example tables with some values.

```sql
CREATE TABLE foods (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(100)
);
CREATE TABLE nutrients (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(100)
);
CREATE TABLE foods_nutrients (
  food_id int REFERENCES foods(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  nutrient_id int REFERENCES nutrients(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  amount DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT food_nutrient_pk PRIMARY KEY (food_id, nutrient_id)
);

INSERT INTO foods(name)
VALUES  ('Apple'),
        ('Banana');
INSERT INTO nutrients(name)
VALUES  ('Carbohydrates'),
        ('Protein'),
        ('Fat');
INSERT INTO foods_nutrients(food_id, nutrient_id, amount)
VALUES  (1, 1, 14.0),
        (1, 2, 0.3),
        (1, 3, 0.2),
        (2, 1, 23.7),
        (2, 2, 1.1);
```

The result of the query should look like this JSON if possible. Or at least close enough. The main problem is the object with the IDs of the nutrients as keys, I think.

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Apple",
    "nutrients": {
      "1": 14.0,
      "2": 0.3,
      "3": 0.2
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Banana",
    "nutrients": {
      "1": 23.7,
      "2": 1.1
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principally `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT()` function is needed to construct a combination between `id`, `name` and `nutrients` values. But `nutrients` requires one more operation which will be using `JSON_OBJECT_AGG()` in order to get a more complicated object. So, consider using

```
WITH fn1 AS
(
SELECT fn.food_id, f.name,
       JSON_OBJECT_AGG( nutrient_id, amount ) AS nutrients                        
  FROM foods_nutrients fn 
  JOIN foods f 
    ON fn.food_id=f.id
  JOIN nutrients n 
    ON fn.nutrient_id=n.id
 GROUP BY fn.food_id, f.name  
)
SELECT JSON_AGG(
                JSON_BUILD_OBJECT( 'id', food_id, 
                                   'name', name,
                                   'nutrients', nutrients) 
                         ) AS js                
  FROM fn1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e7a9509eabfe4a02e618cb20b8c8ee2d)</kbd>

Btw, using `JSONB` equivalents of those functions along with `JSONB_PRETTY()` which nests our current result will yield a nice design as <kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=864d3db0dea5e1952623580a0b1d13da)</kbd>nstrated, just like the format within the question :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple",
        "nutrients": {
            "1": 14.0,
            "2": 0.3,
            "3": 0.2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Banana",
        "nutrients": {
            "1": 23.7,
            "2": 1.1
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below - **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8650cc242fd41c6a1d7a41f5f4e614dc)** Here

```
select row_to_json(fv)
      from (
        select food_id,f.name,json_agg(
                 json_build_object(nutrient_id ,amount) 
            )as nutrients
from foods_nutrients fn join foods f on fn.food_id=f.id
join nutrients n on fn.nutrient_id=n.id group by food_id,f.name   
      ) fv
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much, this is almost what I wanted. Nutrients are an array of objects now: [{"1" : 14.1}, {"2" : 0.3}, {"3" : 0.2}] . Is it possible to return just an object like this: {"1" : 14.1, "2" : 0.3, "3" : 0.2} ?